# Group countries to right continent and set filter for all continents in PivotChart

Tags: excel, pivot-chart

I have an excel data where orders from all over the world are listed. Now, I want to group the countries by their continents, and all continents to one "Continents"-Field to use it as a filter in my PivotChart. I have tried it already with the group function in excel but when I checked/unchecked the fields, the filters get broken. Hope someone can help.

At the moment I get the field with the name "COUNTRY_NAME" from MS Access which contains the specific country from where the order is coming.

[image]

Now, I want to group the countries to their continents to choose the continents instead of countries as a new filter

[image]

I do not use any VBA. Thx in advance!

Greets,
Jochbart

Comment: We can't help unless we can see your data, at least an example, plus the formulas and/or the VBA you're attempting to use.

Comment: Personally I'd just make a new column with "Continents" if you are dealing with a limited number of countries and just write an IF statement to populate it.

Comment: But I get my data automatically from access every night. It refreshs the excel sheet then.

Comment: Is Access overwriting the entire tab? Or just some data in the tab?

Comment: Access is overwriting the entire excel sheet.